# Any scriptural references of Hanuman being known as Giridhara- Upholder of Mountain?

Tags: krishna, ramayana, hanuman, name

"Giridhara" literally means Holder of the Mountain.

When Shri Krishna wanted to break the ego of Indra, Shri Krishna lifted Govardhan mountain on his finger. After this He was given the name Giridhara - the one who holds a mountain.

In the [Ramayana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selaginella_bryopteris), when Ravana's son Indrajit hurls a powerful weapon at Lakshmana, Lakshmana is badly wounded and is nearly killed by Indrajit. Hanuman was called upon to fetch *Sanjivani buti* from Himalayas. After reaching the mountain, **Hanuman unable to identify the herb lifted the entire Dronagiri mountain and brought it to the battlefield. Hanumaan too lifted the mountain Dronagiri.**

When Krishna lifted mountain Govardhana, He is called GiriDhara. **But why is not Hanumaan called GiriDhara? Or are there any references calling Him GiriDhara- Holder of Mountain?**

Comment: On a side note, after that Sanjivani incident Hanuman is famous as **Sankat Mochan Hanuman** - The one who removes your worries.

Comment: Yes, it was also possible for him to get that name . But people did not call him like that . Since giridhari name is not related to father or mother it can be given to any God who holds mountain . Only, Nandakumara , ramanuja - such names cannot be given to other Gods.

Comment: As suruveche says, it's just a matter of historical accident; once one person comes to be associated with a particular name, it's hard to refer to other gods by that name.

Comment: By the way, contrary to popular belief, the incident where Lakshmana was wounded and Hanuman carried the mountain had nothing to do with Indrajit; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2348/36

Comment: -1: This is not real question. "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145678/187039))

Comment: well, how come suddenly this Q become off-topic almost after 1+ years? Anyways I am ok with it.

Comment: @AnuragSingh This is still not a real question even after your edits. I suggest you change the title of the question to "are there any references calling Hanuman Giridhara - Holder of Mountain?" to make it a valid question. E.g., if you or I lift a mountain too, now a third person comes along and asks why aren't we called Giridhara too :P (it makes for an interesting topic for a chat but it's not a real, answerable question for this site)