# Karna's Sakti Weapon

Tags: mahabharata

Lord Krishna said after Karna fired his Sakti weapon at Ghatotkasha that even his Sudarsha Chakra was incapable of stopping the Sakti Weapon. My question is: Why Krishna, being the Lord of the universe, was incapable of stopping a weapon given to Karna by Indra?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Where did you hear that Krishna said that?  Then closest thing I could find in the Drona Parva of the Mahabharata is [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07177.htm) where Krishna says "Indeed, if [Karna] that bull among men had his armour and ear-rings, neither thyself, bending the Gandiva, **nor myself, uplifting my discus, called Sudarsana**, could vanquish him in battle" which admittedly is an equally strange statement.

Comment: Yes. That means Lord Krishna was not capable of defeating Karna, who was a human being. And, Krishna, the Lord of the universe!!! This is strange indeed...

Comment: That is Lord Krishna for you. There is no way you can understand his actions. So, about an avatara of the Lord, then it is impossible to understand the Supreme Lord Narayana. Mind you the Karna was worsted by Arjuna when he fought the entire Kaurava army, single handedly during the Virata parva. Even Bhima had deafeated Karna, that too in dhanur yuddha during kurushetra war. These are just pure leelas of the Lord.

Comment: I do not see this as a mere leela, but there must be deeper meaning as you see Krishna using Ghatotkasha to take away the Shati weapon from Karna. Take another instance...Krishna put his entire weight to push down his chariot when Karna fired the Nag weapon...If Krishna did not do so, Arjuna would have been killed....

Comment: @InduBhusanNath - Karna ran away during Virata Parva, else he would have been killed there it self by Arjuna. Please read how many times, Karna ran away from the battlefield of Kurukshetra. Cannot, but laugh at such theories and people who think Karna is invincible. What is wrong in Krishna saving Arjuna, because truth always wins. Krishna only said he will not take up weapons? If that is the case bhagadatta should be the greatest warrior because when he uses Vaisnavastra, Krishna protects Arjuna. Krishna says that no  one including, Brahma, Siva etc can survive this Vaisnavastra.

Comment: @Krishna But what does the quote from the Drona Parva in my comment above mean?  Why would Krishna say that neither the Gandiva bow nor the Sudarshana Chakra could kill Karna if he had the armor and earrings?

Comment: @Keshav - Krishna even tells Yudhisthira that he shifted capital from mathura to Dwaraka due to fear of Jarasandha. But, we very well know, that Krishna defeated Jarasandha 17 times and even stopped Balarama from killing Jarasandha. So, how do you reconcile the fear expressed by Krishna about Jarasandha? Krishna is feigning fear. One answer might be that Krishna is motivating Arjuna, by trying to portray Karna as superior. This would in turn make Arjuna, fight with more vigour to prove himself.

Comment: @Krishna Yeah, it's definitely plausible that Krishna is saying it as part of some kind of leela, but I don't think he's trying to make Arjuna try to prove himself.  In the context of the chapter, he's trying to cheer up Arjuna after the death of Ghatotkacha.  So he's pointing out how all the advantages that Karna used to have, like the armor, earrings, Indrastra, etc., are all gone now, so Arjuna will be able to beat him.

Comment: @Keshav- Arjuna had brahmastra and Pasupata. He could have, easily, eliminated karna using any of them. Why didnt Arjuna use those? Even if Karna had used Shakti against Arjuna, Krishna would have protected him. But, people will question Arjuna's prowess. So, cheering or motivating by praising Karna will make Arjuna more eager to eliminate Karna. Now, had Karna not used Shakti against, Ghatotkacha, Kaurava army would have been eliminated. So, no way for Karna. He had to decide to die at the hands of Gatotkacha or kill him and postpone his own death to further date at the hands of Arjuna.

Comment: But, please remember that after Karna having killed Ghatotkasha with his Sakti weapon, Krishna said that he was keeping Arjuna away from Karna, and did not bring Arjuna to close proximity with Karna. He also told Bhima that if Karna would not have killed Ghatotkasha, Arjuna would have been the ultimate victim of that Sakti weapon. So, does that do not mean that Krishna was actually unable to neutralize that Sakti weapon? Also, can anyone say what is the origin of that Sakti weapon?

Comment: Does anyone understand everything that Krishna does or say? No. You are trying to infer things. Do you think Krishna would have allowed the Shakti weapon to harm or injure Arjuna? No Way. The only reason, is that instead of he having to save Arjuna, ghatotkacha, he had to bear the brunt. Remember, Ghatotkacha was rakshasa and he too needs to be eliminated. Otherwise who knows may be krishna himself might have been required to kill Ghatotkacha. I dont undestand the sychophancy towards fools like Karna and co. Infact, it was Karna who is directly resposible all the misdeeds of Duryodhana

Comment: Yes, Krishna said that Ghatotkasha was killed because he was creating terror amongst the rishis. But, as a matter of fact, he also said to Arjuna that since Karna lost his Sakti weapon victory of Pandavas was sure. Krishna futher said that even his Sudarshan Chakra was not able to stop that Sakti weapon. So, Krishna's incapability was clear...

Comment: @Indubhusanath- Shakti is a weapon of Indra, given to karna as a return for Karna giving away his kavacha and kundala. Can you please in what context Krishna told Arjuna and Pandavas the above statement quoted by you? Now, coming to Krsishna saying that even his Sudarshana Chakra cannot stop it,  Krishna gives many such statements wherein he feigns fear and inability. This is just to test people who try to read something beyween the lines and start quetioning the Lord

Comment: @Indubhusannath- Also, remember Indra has given a boon to Karna that Shakti will kill anyone on whom this weapon is thrown. IF krishna, stops it then Indra boon will proved as false. That is the reason Krishna says all these. Shakti is weapon provided by Indra

Comment: @Krishna--Can you tell me about the origin of the Sakti weapon? I mean who gave that weapon to Indra?

Comment: @Indubusannath- it is the weapon of Indra. Nobody gave it to him.

Comment: If the Sakti was the weapon of Indra, and no other Gods, like Shiva, Durga gave it to him; then there is no question that it can be powerful than Sudarshan Chakra. In the meantime, Indrajeet, of Ramayana, had injured Lakshmana with the Sakti weapon, I read it somewhere.

Comment: @IndubhusanNath- I think you havent read my previous comments. Sakti astra cannot stand in front of Sudarshana chakra. Now, i understand why you dont want to accept that Indra has weapon called Sakti? Neither Siva nor Durga nor Kali gave that weapon to Indra. Indra is not a joker, like he is portrayed in serials like devon ka dev and other junk serials. In Ramayana, in yuddha khanda, Indra brings all the dead vanaras back to life.

Comment: @Krishna--Thanks for the information. Now, I understand everything, clearly. Now, it is time for starting new discussion. Thanks again....

Comment: @InduBhusanNath Contrary to popular belief, Indrajit did not injure Lakshmana with a Shakti weapon.  See my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2348/36

Comment: Karna ,with his armour was invincible. Krishna knew this. He also knew karna was a great warrior and better than Arjuna. In fact that is why he only revealed Karna's reality to him and not to the Pandavas. Arjun even though he had Krishna could not defeat Karna in a fair fight and krishna knew that Karna, Bhishma and Duryodhan could not be defeated by even the Gods if they fought using their primary weapons that is why he cheated to ensure Pandavas won. Same thing happened in Ramayan when Rama and Laxman realizing that they could not defeat indrajeet in a fair fight attacked him while he was p

Comment: @Krishna "_Arjuna had brahmastra and Pasupata. He could have, easily, eliminated karna using any of them. Why didn't Arjuna use those?_" - Arjuna and Karna used Brahmastra on each other and they canceled out. From [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08091.htm): "Beholding it, Karna, invoking the **brahmastra**, showered his shafts upon Dhananjaya, and once more made an effort to extricate his car. Partha also, by the aid of the brahmastra, poured arrowy downpours upon Karna. Baffling with his own weapon the weapon of his foe, the son of Pandu continued to strike him."

Comment: @Krishna The Pasupata is not meant to be used on mortals: "Thereupon Mahadeva, well-pleased, granted to me the mighty weapon, Pasupata. And, having granted that eternal weapon, he also said unto me, **This must never be hurled at mortals. If discharged at any person of small energy, it would consume the universe.**"

Comment: @sv.: If Pasupata was not meant to be used againt mortals, then why Shiva gave it to Arjuna? In the Kurukshetra war, Arjuna was meant to fight with mortals only....

Comment: @InduBhusanNath See my question [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8997/2995) and answer by @ Tezz

Comment: shakti weapon was of diamond, the whole diamond where as sudershan was all gold

Comment: when Karna gave Indra his Kavacha and earings that where to protect him from all kind of divine weapons , he recieved the Sakti weapon , Krsna is the death of all beings in this world He has stated so in Bhagavad Gita , that time I am and I have come to destroy all, so sooner or later Karna would be killed. Karna used Indras Sakti weapon to kill Ghatokacha as he was destroying the whole Kaurava army , so Krsna spoke these words in some respect to Karna having exchanged his natural born Kavacha with Indra.Krsna and Visnu always favors Lord Visnu and incarnate to destroy Indras enemies .

Comment: .Plus it was time for Ghatotkacha to go back to Godhead to the abode of Krsna ,so he being killed by Karna in Krsnas presence send him straight to Goloka Vrindavana

Answer (score 1):

An avatar voluntarily chooses not to access all knowledge and power for reasons known best to them. Rajiv Malhotra talks about this in his book:

> "The avatar role-plays with deliberate and voluntary self-limitation.
>   The avatar has infinite knowledge which he can choose to access,
>   though ordinarily he does not, or else does so selectively"

I imagine this is applicable in the context of Krishna not stopping the Sakti weapon .

-Excerpt from the book 'Being Different'