# What is the Pashupatastra? Did Arjuna use it in the Kurukshetra war?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, krishna, arjuna, pashupatastra

- What is the Pashupatastra?
- Why did Lord Shiva get it in first place?
- Did Arjuna really use it in the Kurukshetra war? If he didn't, why did he get it from Lord Shiva?
- Was it the all-knowing Krishna who urged Arjuna to acquire this *astra*?
- With regard to today's nuclear weapons, it is often said that they would result in [MAD (Mutually Assured Destruction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction) meaning both the assailant and the target would be destroyed. However, owning one supposedly has the advantage of being used as a deterrent, so in hindsight, was that Pashupatastra's real purpose in the Mahabharatha war?

Comment: Arjun has taken the oath to not use any of those divaystra. He told Krishna that if dharma is on my side, I will not use those weapons whose invoking is dangerous to mother earth. That's why Krishna was worried about Karna's Shakti received by Indra. He uses brahmashira astra only after Mahabharata war to counter ashvathama astra..

Comment: Looking at the answer that you accepted, the pashupatastra is never to be used against mortals, it will destroy the whole universe blah blah blah. Therefore, it is practically useless in the mahabharata war. One wonders why Arjuna even tried for it. On the other hand I wonder how an immortal can be called an immortal if he/she can be slain. These divyastras have no logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1) What is Pashupatastra ?

Pashupatastra is the personal favourite weapon of Lord Shiva.

Just like weapons of Lord Brahma,

> = Brahmastra, Brahmashirastra, etc...

weapons of Lord Vishnu,

> = Narayanastra, Vaishnavastra, etc..

similarly weapons of Lord Shiva,

> = Pashupatastra, Maheswarastra, Raudrastra, etc...

**Literally,**

> Pasupatastra = Weapon of Pasupati

So, there can be two category. One is special Pasupatastra (which Arjuna received) which is very powerful. One General Category can fall as denoting weapon of Pasupati (ie. It may be any weapons containing power of Pasupati).

General category Pasupatastra is described one time in Mahabharat. It was used by Drona  and Arjuna simply destroyed it. It was not that special Pasupatastra received by Arjuna as Arjuna cuts it simply. Also, Lord Shiva had told 'No man know it..' while giving Pasupatastra to Arjuna. So, it is not that special Pasupatastra. It is just used to denote weapon presided by some subtle power of Pasupati.

> When Drona failed to gain any ascendency over the son of Pandu, the son of Bharadwaja, that warrior acquainted with the course of all weapons, invoked into existence the Aindra, **the Pasupata,** the Tvashtra, the Vayavya, and the Yamya weapons. As soon as those weapons, issued from Drona's bow, **Dhananjaya destroyed them quickly.** *[Drona Parva chapter 188]*

However generally if we call Pashupatastra then the special weapon (which Arjuna had received) is understood.

Lord Shiva himself describes here what Pashupatastra is:

> Bhava replied, **'O powerful one. I will give to thee that favourite weapon of mine called the Pasupata.** O son of Pandu, thou art capable of holding, hurling, and withdrawing it. **Neither the chief himself of the gods, nor Yama, nor the king of the Yakshas, nor Varuna, nor Vayu, knoweth it. How could men know anything of it?** But, O son of Pritha, this weapon should not be hurled without adequate cause; for **if hurled at any foe of little might it may destroy the whole universe. In the three worlds with all their mobile and immobile creatures, there is none who is incapable of being slain by this weapon. And it may be hurled by the mind, by the eye, by words, and by the bow.'"** [VanaParva Chapter 60]

#### 2)Why did Lord Shiva get it in first place?

It is personal weapon of Pasupati. So it is always with him.

> Bhava replied, 'O powerful one. **I will give to thee that favourite weapon of mine called the Pasupata.** O son of Pandu, thou art capable of holding, hurling, and withdrawing it. Neither the chief himself of the gods, nor Yama, nor the king of the Yakshas, nor Varuna, nor Vayu, knoweth it. How could men know anything of it? *[VanaParva Chapter 60]*

Lord Shiva had united Pasupatastra with Shaft used in the Tripura Dahana incident:

> **Then Sarva, having stringed his bow and
> aimed that shaft with which he had united the Pasupata weapon, waited thinking of the triple city.** And O king, as Rudra thus stood, holding his bow, the three cities during that time became united. When the
> three cities, losing their separate characters became united, tumultuous became the joy of the high-
> souled gods. Then all the gods, the Siddhas, and the great Rishis, uttered the word Jaya, adoring
> Maheshwara. *[Karna Parva Chapter 34]*

#### 3) Was it the all-knowing Krishna who urged Arjuna to acquire this astra?

Arjuna had received Pasupatastra two times from Lord Shiva. At first time by the words of Indra, Arjuna starts penance for Lord Shiva:

> **Thus addressed, the slayer of Vritra,** worshipped of the worlds, consoling him with gentle words, spare unto the son of Pandu, saying, '**When thou art able to behold the three-eyed trident-bearing Siva, the lord of all creatures, it is then, O child, that I will give thee all the celestial weapons.** Therefore, strive thou to obtain the sight of the highest of the gods; for it is only after thou hast seen him. O son of Kunti, that thou will obtain all thy wishes.' Having spoken thus unto Phalguna, Sakra disappeared then and there, and Arjuna, devoting himself to asceticism, remained at that spot." *[VanaParva chapter 37]*

But as long time had passed Arjuna forgots the knowledge to invoke Pasupatastra during Kurukshetra war. Thus before the day of Jayadratha Vadh Lord Krishna by Yogic path took him to Kailash to receive Pasupatastra again.

> Through his grace thou shalt obtain that rich possession.' Hearing these words of Krishna, Dhananjaya, having touched water, sat on the earth with concentrated mind and thought of the god Bhava. After he had thus sat with rapt mind at that hour called Brahma of auspicious indications, Arjuna saw himself journeying through the sky with Kesava. *[Drona Parva Chapter 80]*

Then both of them gratified Lord Shiva and Arjuna received Pasupatastra one more time.

> And the god also granted him the terrible Pasupata weapon and the accomplishment of his vow. **Then having thus once more obtained the Pasupata weapon from the supreme god,** the invincible Arjuna, with hair standing on end, regarded his business to be already
> achieved. Then Arjuna and Krishna filled with joy, paid their adorations unto the great god by bowing their heads. And permitted by Bhava both Arjuna and Kesava, those two heroes, almost immediately
> came back to their own camp, filled with transports of delight. *[Drona Parva Chapter 80]*

#### 4)Did Arjuna really use it in the Kurukshetra war? If he didn't, why did he get it from Lord Shiva?

Pashupatastra was never used in Kurukshetra war. There is popular misconception that Arjuna had used it to slay Jayadratha. It is not true.

Arrow which killed Jayadratha was like this:

> Sorely afflicting those mighty car-warriors of thy army thus, the son of Pandu took up a terrible arrow of fiery splendour. Looking like the thunderbolt of Indra, and inspired with divine mantras, that formidable arrow was capable of bearing any strain. And it had been always worshipped with incense and garlands of flowers. Duly inspiring it (by mantras) with the force of the thunderbolt, that descendant, of Kuru, viz., the mighty-armed Arjuna, fixed it on Gandiva. *[Jayadratha Vadh Parva]*

**Then why Did Lord Krishna took him to Kailash to receive Pasupatastra  before the day of Jayadratha Vadha?**

It is because just knowledge of invoking Pasupatastra is sufficient to make one victorious and powerful. It works subtly.

> And then that hero, of eyes like lotus leaves, and possessed of great energy, said these words for the benefit of Pandu's son who had resolved upon the slaughter of the ruler of the Sindhus, **'O Partha, there is an indestructible, supreme weapon of the name of Pasupata.** With it the god Maheswara slew in battle all the Daityas! **If thou rememberest it now, thou shalt then be able to slay Jayadratha tomorrow.** If it is unknown to thee (now), adore within thy heart the god having the bull for his mark. Thinking of that god in thy mind, remember him, O Dhananjaya! *[Drona Parva Chapter 80]*

Furthermore, Pasupatastra is not a weapon which is to be hurled to mortals. It was to be used only in extreme emergency.

> Then the god Tryamvaka said unto me, 'I will give. O Pandava, my own weapon Raudra shall attend upon thee.' Thereupon Mahadeva, well-pleased, granted to me the mighty weapon, Pasupata. And, having granted that eternal weapon, he also said unto me, **This must never be hurled at mortals. If discharged at any person of small energy, it would consume the universe.** Shouldst thou (at any time) be hard pressed, thou mayst discharge it. And when all thy weapons have been completely baffled, thou mayst hurl it.'  *[Vana Parva chapter 166]*

Comment: Good answer, but I'm not convinced on #4. Seems like the Pasupata could have been used to counter Karna's Shakti but Krishna did not think so. Also if Pasupata had worked subtly, Arjuna did not need to rely on Krishna to temporarily mask the Sun to slay Jayadratha.

Comment: @sv. Counter of Vasavi sakti wasn't possible..it was due to boon of Indra... see my answer here... http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12502/was-vasavi-sakti-more-powerful-than-pasupata   Pasupata worked subtly because mass annihilation was needed that day... Arjuna killed the highest number of soldier that day... if Pasupata didn't worked subtly then why did Krishna took Arjun to get Pasupatastra again?... we can't tell that Krishna did that thing without any logic/reason...

Comment: If Krishna said "If thou rememberest it now, thou shalt then be able to slay Jayadratha tomorrow." and then he didn't need to help Arjuna, but he did. BTW, in SB, it's [mentioned](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/63/13) that Shiva himself uses the Pasupata on Krishna and it was countered. So it can be definitely used against Indra's Shakti. Shiva also tells Arjuna "Should you (at any time) be hard pressed, you may discharge it. And when all your weapons have been completely baffled, you may hurl it." - so he could have used it against Karna.

Comment: @sv. Yes, and I guesseed right... The authentic story of Harivamsa doesn't tells Pasupatastra used on Krishna.. it is a self made story made by SB... Read here... http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_124.html

Comment: @sv. if Arjuna countered Shakti of Karna... then what would happen to Prarabdha Karma of Ghatotkacha... he was destined to die from hand of Karna by that weapon... so, why would Krishna change Prarabdha Karma of someone..? In the battle of Jarasandha also Krishna fights with him 17 times but doesn't kill him... when asked by Balarama why ne didn't kill... then he tells "He is destined to die from hand of Bhima. So, I'm sparing him.."... so God don't interfere in Prarabdha Karma of anyone...

Comment: "then what would happen to Prarabdha Karma of Ghatotkacha" - If Ghatotkacha was destined to die at the hands of Karna, Krishna would not have to keep on protecting Arjuna from possible encounters with Karna and also make him forget his Shakti weapon. The 'Prarabdha Karma' of Ghatotkacha doesn't need Krishna's intervention...

Comment: I think Krishna took Arjuna to get Shiva's blessings, that's all, to boost Arjuna's confidence.

Answer (score 3):

The Pashupatastra is an irresistible and most destructive personal weapon of Shiva, Kali and Adi Para Sakti discharged by the mind, the eyes, words, or a bow. It was Never to be used against lesser enemies or by lesser warriors, if used then the Pashupatastra was capable of destroying creation and vanquishing all beings. It is said that Lord Shiva obtained Pashupatastra from Adi Para Sakti by intense penance before the creation of the Brahmand. Pashupatastra can be neutralized by personal weapon of Adi para shakti or by a another Pashupatastra .

In Mahabharata, Arjuna used this astra to slay Jayadaratha. It is said that the mantra to obtain and discharge the astra is sealed by Shiva to prevent its misuse in the Kali Yuga. It is said that no one in the three worlds can resist Lord Shiva when he shows his prowess. Apart from Arjuna, Bhisma, Drona and Karna also possessed Pashupatastra so Lord Krishna must have advised him so that Arjun remains at par with them.

A Narrative from KMG translation of Mahabharat regarding the power of Pashupatastra:

> O thou of mighty arms, that weapon(Pashupatastra) is superior to the Brahma, the Narayana, the Aindra, the Agneya, and the Varuna weapons. Verily, it is capable of neutralising every other weapon in the universe. It was with that weapon that the illustrious Mahadeva had in days of yore, burnt and consumed in a moment the triple city of the Asuras. With the greatest ease, O Govinda, Mahadeva, using that single arrow, achieved that feat. That weapon, shot by Mahadeva's arms, can, without doubt consume in half the time taken up by a twinkling of the eyes the entire universe with all its mobile and immobile creatures. In the universe there is no being including even the deities, that are incapable of being slain by that weapon.

Source: [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashupatastra)

Comment: _Lord Krishna **must have** advised him_: I'm looking for a more conclusive, less speculative answer. Can you please cite sources (other than wiki) for _Arjuna used this astra to slay Jayadaratha_?

Comment: Also, see the discussion regarding Pashupatastra in the comments of this [answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2945/2995)

Comment: The Mahabharata doesn't say that Jayadratha was killed with a Pashupastra. "Sorely afflicting those mighty car-warriors of thy army thus, the son of Pandu took up a terrible arrow of fiery splendour. Looking like the thunderbolt of Indra, and inspired with divine mantras, that formidable arrow was capable of bearing any strain. And it had been always worshipped with incense and garlands of flowers. Duly inspiring it (by mantras) with the force of the thunderbolt, that descendant, of Kuru, viz., the mighty-armed Arjuna, fixed it on Gandiva." http://http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07142.htm

Comment: It sounds like it's talking about the Indrastra, not the Pashupatastra.

Comment: @aby Did Karna have Pasupatastra?

Comment: No, Karna did not have Pasupata

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting conversation. My humble view added on couple of points in the above conversation.

Destroying Jayadratha didn't necessarily call for special powers. In fact Jayadratha himself didn't believe he seriously stood a chance against Arjuna. The moment Arjuna's vow came to his knowledge, he decided to flee and go into hiding. Duryodhana saw an opportunity to trap Arjuna, since Arjuna was bound to kill himself if he didn't succeed in killing Jayadratha by evening, so he persuaded Jayadratha to stay back and assured him of utmost protection. The battle on that evening became tough because Jayadratha was hidden behind ranks and ranks of army that made it almost unassailable to get closer to him. It wasn't because of his invincibility or anything of that sort. It's precisely to bring him out out of cover and expose himself that Krishna deployed his will to temporarily conceal sunlight on that evening. Technically, there was no compelling need to use special weapons especially ones like Pasupathastra on Jayadratha.

Yes, it is possible to argue that it could have been reserved for Karna, who was the ultimate challenge for Arjuna. Again, Krishna Bhagawan knew that there were several factors working against Karna and those would eventually conspire against him, which was not a common knowledge for others. Krishna was only worried about Sakthi Ayudha, which by circumstances were used against Ghatotkacha. According to Mahabharat, when Ghatotkacha was hit by Karna's special weapon (which he was allowed to use only once), Krishna apparently smiled and gave a happy reaction which annoyed Bhima. Of course, nobody at that time would have understood what caused a relief that made Krishna to smile.

Comment: *"You said according to Mahabharata, Krishna smiled...."* can you please cite where it is? Citations are encouraged in this site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got answer to 1st and 2nd question.

> Did Arjuna really use it in the Kurukshetra war? If he didn't, why did he get it from Lord Shiva?

NO . Arjun never used it in his whole lifetime . In some links its mentioned that Arjun used it to slay Jayadrath but as per **THE MOST AUTHENTIC KMG edition or BORI critical edition** Arjun didnt use . It is mentioned that Krishna advised Arjun but Arjun didnt use it .

> Hearing these words (of Krishna), Dhananjaya, licking the corners of his mouth, quickly shot that arrow which he had taken up for Jayadratha's slaughter, that arrow, viz., whose touch resembled that of Indra's thunder, which was inspired with mantras and converted into a celestial weapon, which was capable of bearing any strain, and which had always been worshipped with incense and garlands. That shaft, sped from Gandiva, coursing swiftly, snatched Jayadratha's head away, like a hawk snatching away a smaller bird from the top of a tree. Dhananjaya, then, with his shafts, sent that head along in the welkin (without allowing it to fall down

Here you can see nowhere Arjun used Pashupatastra

Shiva gave it to Arjun to use it only to preserve dharma and he has no other alternatives .

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.  If what you're saying is there in the Mahabharata, you should give the relevant quote.

Answer (score 1):

I think that  arjun  had that  divine  pashupatastra that  lord  Shiva  used  to  destroy  tripura  city &that  weapon  could  have finished  t war  on  t very  1st  day! !?had  he  used  it? But wasn't  he  supposed  to be  on dharma 'S side? So  he  could nt, ,,,and  all  those  karna  lovers  who  always  cry  for  unfair  means  by  which  karn was  killed and  that  if  he  had  his  kavach&kundal he  wd  me invincible =,,,,first  they  need  to  know  t  truth  about  those kavach&kundal (999 kavach&kundal  of 1000 had  been destroyed by  NAR &NARAYAN  in the  previous  yuga of rakshash damboduvna which  was  given  as  a boon  by Surya dev,, ,,,karn  got  t  last  one  of  that kavach&kundal on  his  birth ~he was reincarnation  of  that  raksash! !!!ARJUN&LORD  KRISHNA  were reincarnation of NAR &NARAYAN of TRETA yug #####.now can anyone put  some  COMMON SENSE to all the karn lovers  that  if 999 of those  armour  could  be  destroyed  ,,,,why couldn't 1000th be? ?????????????????TELL ME..

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Please format the answer and cite sources. You  can cite Mahabharata, for instance.

Comment: Please register. Improve formatting to make your post easy for reading. Here is the [editing help](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

- **What is the Pashupatastra?**

Pashupatastra was a weapon of Lord Shiva with 1000 eyes, 1000 heads, 1000 stomachs, 1000 arms 1000 tounges and one foot which could destroy any weapon in the world.

> **Possessed of one foot, of large teeth, and a thousand heads and thousand Stomachs, it has a thousand arms, a thousand tongues, and a thousand eyes.** Indeed, it seemed to continually vomit fire. O thou of mighty arms, **that weapon is superior to the Brahma, the Narayana, the Aindra, the Agneya, and the Varuna weapons. Verily, it is capable of neutralising every other weapon in the universe.** It was with that weapon that the illustrious Mahadeva had in days of yore, burnt and consumed in a moment the triple city of the Asuras. With the greatest ease, O Govinda, Mahadeva, using that single arrow, achieved that feat. That weapon, shot by Mahadeva's arms, can, without doubt consume in half the time taken up by a twinkling of the eyes the entire universe with all its mobile and immobile creatures. **In the universe there is no being including even Brahma and Vishnu and the deities, that are incapable of being slain by that weapon.**
>
> http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a014.htm

Pashupatastra was also known as Raudraastra.

> Then the god Tryamvaka said unto me, 'I will give. O Pandava, my own weapon **Raudra** shall attend upon thee.' Thereupon Mahadeva, well-pleased, granted to me the mighty weapon, **Pasupata**.
>
> http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03166.htm

In some places, *Pashupatastra* is described as a weapon with 3 heads,9eyes and 6 arms of Lord Vishnu, Lord Agni and Lord Soma.

> **Vishnu and Agni and Soma became (as already said) the arrow.** The universe is said to consist of Agni and Soma. The universe is similarly said to consist of Vishnu.........Then Sarva, having stringed his bow and aimed that shaft with which he had united the **Pasupata weapon**, waited thinking of the triple city. And O king, as Rudra thus stood, holding his bow, the three cities during that time became united.
>
> http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08034.htm
>
> I fixed that mighty weapon which, celebrated under the name of **Raudra**, is the destroyer of all foes. Then I beheld a male person having **three heads, nine eyes, three faces, and six arms**. 
>   http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03172.htm

- **Why did Lord Shiva get it in first place?**

*Pashupatastra* was a very powerful weapon of Lord Shiva but neither it was the strongest weapon of the world nor the strongest weapon of Shiva. Lord Shiva had another weapon superior to Pashupatastra.

> **There is another mysterious and very powerful weapon which is equal or perhaps, superior to the Pasupata weapon. I beheld that also. It is celebrated in all the worlds as the Sum of the Sula-armed Mahadeva.**
>
> http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a014.htm

This weapon was later gifted to Lord Parashurama.

- **Did Arjuna really use it in the Kurukshetra war? If he didn't, why did he get it from Lord Shiva?**

**Yes.** Arjuna used that weapon against Jayadrath.

> O Partha, there is an indestructible, supreme weapon of the name of **Pasupata**. With it the god Maheswara slew in battle all the Daityas! **If thou rememberest it now, thou shalt then be able to slay Jayadratha tomorrow.**
>
> http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07077.htm

He used this weapon against Karna.

> **Approaching Karna, strike him with superior weapons."** Then Dhananjaya, filled with rage, inspiring with mantras another celestial weapons that looked like fire and that resembled the poison of the snake and that was as hard as the essence of adamant, and uniting the **Raudra weapon with it,** became desirous of shooting it at his foe.
>
> http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08090.htm

Before Kurukshetra war, that weapon was used by Arjuna against kalakanjas.

> And being afflicted by those innumerable ones, equipped in weapons and skilled in fight, I was pained in that mighty encounter and a terrible fear seized me. Thereupon collecting (my energies) in fight, I (bowed down) unto that god of gods, Raudra, and saying, 'May welfare attend on all beings!' I fixed that mighty weapon which, celebrated under the name of Raudra, is the destroyer of all foes.
>
> http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03172.htm

- Was it the all-knowing Krishna who urged Arjuna to acquire this astra?

Arjuna got Pashupatastra through penance but he forgot the use of the weapon and Lord Krishna helped him in getting again that weapon in
[Drona Parva.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://en.krishnakosh.org/krishna/Mahabharata_Drona_Parva_Chapter_80&ved=2ahUKEwiyotfrrLrpAhWcyDgGHQOdDywQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2bY0ZPV0zRESy85kLPzd_c)

- With regard to today's nuclear weapons, it is often said that they would result in MAD (Mutually Assured Destruction) meaning both the assailant and the target would be destroyed. However, owning one supposedly has the advantage of being used as a deterrent, so in hindsight, was that Pashupatastra's real purpose in the Mahabharatha war?

Comment: "Yes. Arjuna used that weapon against Jayadrath." - your blockquote doesn't support this statement. It only talks about the possibility of using it.