# Is there any difference between religious books and religious tv serials?

Tags: ramayana

Few days ago I had an arguments with one person on instagram on one topic. suddenly our discussion turns towards Shree Ram and our discussion turned into religious topic. Here are some parts of discussions (as I remember) which will help you to understand what is my question.

- **He:** Civilised people is not what you are saying because even Shree Ram killed bali with fraud, how you will see Ram on this?
- **Me:** Don't give example of Shree Ram without knowing the full truth. He did it on purpose of protecting dharma and spread justice
  in world. I use to watch Ramanand Sagar's Ramayan on YouTube almost
  daily. I know all fact about it. If you wanna know more on it then go
  and watch by yourself.
- **He:** ahaha you are telling me on behalf of a tv serial lol. What you will find from a serial. Go and read Ramayan and Ram
  Charitmanas... Only after reading these books you will come to know
  about it.
- **Me:** (got little agry after reading his last comment) Why not tv serial? You think books are more genuine than TV serial? May be you
  don't know but let me tell you for your information that the books
  that you use to read are Published by companies and writer of those
  books will be a writer from today's time. If you will see writer name
  of Ramayan then you won't see Balmiki written on it but instead it
  will be name of some writter who just wrote this book. The actual
  Ramayan of Balmiki can't be found. So the writer of books and writer
  of TV serial script are both from today's time, not from Satyug or
  DwaparYug. Then on what basis you believe books are more genuine than
  serial since both are written by companies (publisher company and tv
  serial maker company).
- **He:** (stated laughing at me and earagantly reply with some very bad words) I read books and also watch serials, so I know what's the
  difference between them. Go and read books then you will come to
  know.

**Note**: Although he said he knows the difference since he has seen both but still I believe he just faking it so that he won't loose the arguments and the bad words he used in last comments (that i didn't mentioned) are proove of this coz when people start loosing any arguments then they start getting personal.

But now I actually want to know is there any difference between knowledge provides by books and TV serial? Both shares same incidents of Lord Ram's life and teachings then what could be possible difference between them.

Can't I say that I know all about my Lord Ram's life because I have watched Ramanad Sagar's Ramayan? Or I will be applicable of saying this only when I will read Ram Charitmanas?

**UPDATE**

I got some useful comments but still not got clear answer. I know serials can add stuff to increase TRP but I am not talking about all serial but only Ramand Sagar's Ramayan because I believe this is most trustworty serial ever made on Ramayan.

If some one has read books and also watch serial of Ramanad Sagar then Please point out what difference are there. Give example of some incident which are in book but not in serial and which are in serial but not in book.

Right now I am getting reply only based on assumptions which might be right or might be wrong.

Comment: Such serials are mostly based on one or more relevant scriptures only. But i don't think that we can always trust them.

Comment: What sources are considered authentic varies from person to person. For e.g. BR Chopra's Mahabharata is much more authentic than recent Mahabharata, which is better called Mega-Bharata since they made it like mega tv serial with their own idiotic stories and interpolations added.

The original version of Valmiki Ramayana does exist today in Sanskrit. But like you said, their translations or interpretations may not be authentic. To truly understand author's intent, we have to first Practice Dharma, Speak Truth.
This argument about whether to believe a book or serial is mostly subjective.

Comment: You can always read the original Ramayana at valmikiramayan.net which I think would be good as TV serials tend to change facts here and there. (It's true though not completely for Ramanand Sagar but) the book - **Valmiki Ramayana in Sanskrit** is most authentic.

Comment: Even Ramanand Sagar's Ramanaya differs from VR at some places. See [Why did Laxman get injured by Indrajit's 'shakti' weapon?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2341/3500). Scriptures in Sanskrit are authentic. Translations and intepretation may vary from person to person. But Rama did no mistake. [Why did Lord Rama strike from behind to kill Vaali?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/236/3500). Rama and Dharma are synonymous. All we need to do is, to read Valmiki Ramayana properly.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59040/discussion-on-question-by-rishabh-is-there-any-difference-between-religious-book).

Comment: @TheDestroyer I don't think future viewers will be interested to view chat in separate chat section. Some useful comments are there which won't be read by future viewers now and since no one posted any answer then post become complete useless now since even comments moved to chat.

Comment: Purpose of chat room is to make users chat in proper GUI. Since, this discussion is still going on, it's better if we discuss in chat room.

Comment: No. Rely more on Scriptures. The older Ramayana and Mahabharata are still enough reliable, but do not at all go with today's spiritual TV serials. They turn the story to what no related point, to make it more interesting. Scriptures​ are only to be relied upon.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Yes, I am aware that today's ramyan are not worthy of trust. They just faking mostly. I only believe in Ramanand Sagar's Ramayan.