# Origin of Ravana's name

Tags: ravana, name, resource

What is the story reference of Ravana, who made a loud cry (thus deriving this name ) crushed by Shiva? { When proud Ravana tried to lift and trouble Shiva on the Kailash mountain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the info which I learned from TV shows **Devo ke Deva Mahadeva** And **Sankat Mochan Mahaabali Hanuman**.

> When Ravana try to pick up Kailash Mountain then Lord Shiva push Mountain with his thumb of foot. The force of even one thumb of Shiva's foot is so much massively powerful that it's become impossible for Ravana to carry mountain and his hands got crush under weight of mountain (because of Shiv'a thumb force).
>
> He start crying with pain. The sound of his cry is that high which got spread in all three world (loks). Mountains near him start shivering with his cry.
> He keep crying for long time (may be years but not sure how long). Because of his that high lever of cry he got named as **Ravana**. Meaning of Ravana is ruddan (ronaa). Finally he got released from his pain when He start singing stuti of Shiva which is created by Ravana himself.
> Shiva liked his stuti so much and released his hands. He appeared in front of him and gave name to his stuti as **Shiva Tandava Srot**. He also gave him Powerful sword named as **Chandrahaas**.

Comment: Nice, I also came across the same narrative. but I meant puranic references.. modern TV can picturize folklore.

Comment: TV shows are not considered valid sources. Please provide some other sources.

Comment: @SreeCharan Valid or Invalid, It is individual's choice. As per site rules I post reference and It is up to individual whether they consider this reference valid or not.

Comment: As per site rules, TV shows are not considered as a source. See this meta post. [Are mythological TV shows going to be counted as source?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/are-mythological-tv-shows-going-to-be-counted-as-source). The community consent is not to allow TV shows. You may cite another source.

Comment: I also raised this question to know [what's defference between TV shows and Books](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18386/is-there-any-difference-between-religious-books-and-religious-tv-serials). But no one could satisfy me with his comments/thoughts.

Comment: [Read this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59040/discussion-on-question-by-rishabh-is-there-any-difference-between-religious-book) and see by yourself that no one has valid point to proof all serials are not trustworthy,

Comment: Writers of the TV shows use artistic imagery and add their own dialogues and stories to entertain people. Can you tell me based on which scripture Sankat mochan serial is? In that show, Hanuman is shown as a prince but he wasn't a prince and his father was not a king. There are numerous examples we can show like these. TV shows are not authentic.That's the rule. You can cite any other source but not a random blog. We don't judge which show is good or bad. All serials are not valid sources.

Answer (score 7):

The story of Ravana's name occurs in [Chapter 16](https://archive.org/stream/TheRamayanaUttaraKandam/The_Ramayana#page/n65/mode/2up) of the **Uttara-Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana**. The Sanskrit text has been taken from [Srimad Valmiki Ramayana Uttar Kanda by DP Sharma](https://archive.org/stream/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SanskritTextWithHindiTranslation-DpSharma10/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SktHindi-DpSharmaVol09-UttaraKandaPurvardh1927#page/n175/mode/2up) and [Sanskrit Documents](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/ramayana/valmiki.htm).

Since the story is a bit long I'm only linking specific verses here.

After Dashanana usurps Kubera's Alkapuri and Pushpaka Vimana he moves towards Kailasha in the Pushpaka. However his vehicle does not move beyond the foot of the mountain.

The Rakshasha wonders why this happened (since Pushpaka can move anywhere according to the will of its owner) and Nandi provides an explanation that Lord Shiva and Parvati do not want their privacy to be disturbed at Kailasha.

Annoyed at his movements being obstructed by Kailasha Dashanana decides to uproot the mountain to strike fear into the heart of the Lord (Shiva).

> अचिन्तयित्वा स तदा नन्दिवाक्यं निशाचरः | 
>     पर्वतं तं समासाद्य वाक्यमेतदुवाच ह ||
>
> पुष्पकस्य गतिश्छिन्ना यत्कृते मम गच्छतः |
>  
>    तदेतच्छैलमुन्मूलं करोमि तव गोपते ||
>
> acintayitvā sa tadā nandivākyaṃ niśācaraḥ | 
>  
>     parvataṃ taṃ samāsādya vākyametaduvāca ha
>
> puṣpakasya gatiśchinnā yatkṛte mama gacchataḥ
>     tadetacchailamunmūlaṃ karomi tava gopate ||
>
> But without heeding Nandi's speech, that highly powerful
>   one-Dasanana-coming to the mountain, said,- O Gopati, I will even
>   uproot this mountain, for whom Pushpaka was deprived of its motion as
>   I was journeying.
>
> केन प्रभावेन भवस्तत्र क्रीडति राजवत् | 
>  
>     विज्ञातव्यं न जानीषे भयस्थानमुपस्थितम्
>
> kena prabhāvena bhavastatra krīḍati rājavat
>     vijñātavyaṃ na jānīṣe bhayasthānamupasthitam
>
> It must be known by what influence Bhavaswara sporteth here king-like. He doth not know that an occasion of fear hath presented itself?'
>
> एवमुक्त्वा ततो राजन्भुजान्प्रक्षिप्य पर्वते |
>   तोलयामास तं शैलं समृगव्यालपादपम् ||
>
> evamuktvā tato rājanbhujānprakṣipya parvate|
>  tolayāmāsa taṃ śailaṃ
>   samṛgavyālapādapam ||
>
> **Having said this, O Rama, Ravana seizing the mountain with his arms,
>   lifted it up at once; and then the mountain trembled greatly.**

Lord Shiva as a sport presses down Kailasha over Dashanana's arms, crushing them and Dashanana emits a loud wail that shakes the entire universe.

> ततो राम महादेवः प्रहसन्वीक्ष्य तत्कृतम् | 
>  
>     पादाङ्गुष्ठेन तं शैलं पीडयामास लीलया
>
> ततस्ते पीडितास्तस्य शैलस्याधो गता भुजाः |
>  
>     विस्मिताश्चाभवंस्तत्र सचिवास्तस्य रक्षसः ||
>
> tato rāma mahādevaḥ prahasanvīkṣya tatkṛtam |
>     pādāṅguṣṭhena taṃ śailaṃ pīḍayāmāsa līlayā ||
>
> tataste pīḍitāstasya śailasyādho gatā bhujāḥ vismitāścābhavaṃstatra
>   sacivāstasya rakṣasaḥ
>
> **And then, O Rama, Mahadeva-foremost of the deities-even Hara, as in
>   sport pressed the mount with his great toe.** And thereat his arms,
>   resembling blocks of stone felt the shock and then there the
>   councilors of that Raksha were struck with amaze.
>
> रक्षसा तेन रोषाच्च भुजानां पीडनात्तथा | 
>  
>     मुक्तो विरावः सुमहांस्त्रैलोक्यं येन पूरितम् ||
>
> rakṣasā tena roṣācca bhujānāṃ pīḍanāttathā | 
>  
>     mukto virāvaḥ sumahāṃstrailokyaṃ yena pūritam
>
> **And the Raksha, from wrath and the pain felt in his arms, set up a
>   shout that shook the entire triune world.** And his councillors
>   considered it as the concussion of the thunder at the universal
>   disruption.

Dashanana's frightened councillors advise him to pray to Mahadeva for forgiveness and he does so for a 1000 years upon which Mahadeva is gratified and releases him bestowing upon him the name Ravana.

> तेषियख महादेवं नीलकण्ठमुमापतिम्। 
>     तमृते शरणं नान्यं पश्यामोऽत्र दशानन
>
> स्तुतिभिः प्रणतो भूत्वा तमेव शरणं व्रज ।
>  
>     कृपालुः शङ्करस्तुष्टः प्रसादं ते विधास्यति
>
> teṣiyakha mahādevaṃ nīlakaṇṭhamumāpatim |
>     tamṛte śaraṇaṃ nānyaṃ paśyāmo'tra daśānana ||
>
> stutibhiḥ praṇato bhūtvā tameva śaraṇaṃ vraja |
>  
>     kṛpāluḥ śaṅkarastuṣṭaḥ prasādaṃ te vidhāsyati ||
>
> 'Do thou propitiate Uma's lord-the blue-throated Mahadeva; for, O
>   Dasanana, save him thy refuge see we none in this matter, Bowing
>   thyself down, do thou seek him as thy shelter, Then the kind Sankara,
>   on being gratified, will confer on thee his favor."
>
> एवमुक्तस्तुदामात्यैस्तुष्टाव तृषभध्वजम् । 
>  
>     सामभिर्विविधैः स्तोत्रैः प्रणम्य स दशानन । 
>     संवत्सरसहस्रं तु रुदते रक्षसाे गतम् ||
>
> evamuktastudāmātyaistuṣṭāva tṛṣabhadhvajam 
>     samabhirvividhaiḥ stotraiḥ praṇamya sa daśānana |
>     saṃvatsarasahasraṃ tu rudate rakṣaso gatam ||
>
> Thus accosted by his councillors, the Ten-faced one, bowing down to
>   him having the bull for his standard, **began to hymn him with various
>   sama hymns; and the Raksha passed away a good thousand years in
>   lamentations**
>
> ततः प्रीतो महादेवः शैलाग्रे विष्ठितस्तदा | 
>     मुक्त्वा तस्य भुजान्राजन्प्राह वाक्यं दशाननम् ||
>
> tataḥ prīto mahādevaḥ śailāgre viṣṭhitastadā |
>     muktvā tasya bhujānrājanprāha vākyaṃ daśānanam ||
>
> **And thereat that Lord Mahādeva, pleased, set free the hands of
>   Dasanana stationed at the top of the mount, and O Rama, addressed him,
>   saying,"O Dashanana, pleased am I with thee on account of thy hymns."**
>
> प्रीतेऽस्मि तव वीर्याच्च शौण्डीर्याच्च निशाचर | 
>  
>     रवतो वेदना मुक्तः खरः परमदारुणः ||
>
> **यस्माल्लोकत्रयं त्वेतद्रावितं भयमागतम् |  
>
>     तस्मात्त्वं रावणो नाम नाम्ना तेन भविष्यसि** ||
>
> prīte.asmi tava vīryācca śauṇḍīryācca niśācara | 
>   ravato vedanā muktaḥ kharaḥ paramadāruṇaḥ ||
>
> **yasmāllokatrayaṃ tvetadrāvitaṃ bhayamāgatam |
>
>     tasmāttvaṃ rāvaṇo nāma nāmnā tena bhaviṣyasi**
>
> **And as in consequence of thy arms having been hurt by the mountain,
>   thou hast uttered a terrific yell, which struck horror into the three
>   worlds and put them shaking, therefore, O King, thy name shall be
>   Ravana.**
>
> देवता मानुषा यक्षा ये चान्ये जगतीतले | 
>     एवं त्वामभिधास्यन्ति **रावणं लोकरावणम्** ||
>
> devatā mānuṣa yakṣā ye cānye jagatītaḻe |
>     evaṃ tvāmabhidhāsyanti **rāvaṇaṃ lokarāvaṇam** ||
>
> And deities and men and Yakshas and others living on earth **shall call
>   thee Ravana-terror to creatures.**
>
> **एवं महेश्वरेणैवं कृतनामा स रावणः** | 
>     अभिवाद्य महादेवं विमानं तत्समारुहत् ||
>
> **evaṃ maheśvareṇaivaṃ kṛtanāmā sa rāvaṇaḥ** | 
>     abhivādya mahādevaṃ vimānaṃ tatsamāruhat ||
>
> **Having thus received his name from Maheswara, Ravana**, saluting
>   Mahadeva, ascended Pushpaka.

Comment: had sung for 1000 years!  I think sahasrar mean many, not 1000 years.

Comment: @Rohit. This Sanskrit Dictionary translates it as "thousand years" http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=HK&beginning=0+&tinput=saMvatsarasahasraM+&trans=Translate